# How to run Spark on Zeppelin to analyze xml files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am able to run Spark shell by `bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.3.0` to analize xml files, for example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rowTag", "book")
    .load("books.xml")
```

but how can I run Zeppelin to do it so. Does Zeppelin need some parameter at start to import `com.databricks.spark.xml`?
Now I am getting:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load class for data source:
>   com.databricks.spark.xml  at
>   scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.lookupDataSource(ddl.scala:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:114)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:104)
>     at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:26)     at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:31)   at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:33)    at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:35)     at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:37)  at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:39)   at $iwC$$iwC.(:41)
>     at $iwC.(:43)    at (:45)     at
>   .(:49)     at .()     at
>   .(:7)  at .()     at $print()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpretInput(SparkInterpreter.java:709)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:674)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:667)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ClassloaderInterpreter.interpret(ClassloaderInterpreter.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:300)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:169)  at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:134)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Zeppelin, you need to call for those dependencies before creating the SparkContext.

In a separate cell you add and run the following

```
%dep
z.reset()
z.addRepo("Spark Packages Repo").url("http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven")
z.load("com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.3.0")
```

If this gives you an error from the type : "You have to add dependencies before starting your SparkContext" just restart the interpreter or Zeppelin.

Comment: What if you don't have the %dep interpreter? On AWS EMR standard zeppelin it doesn't appear to be included. Is there another way to add this package?

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is valid for older versions of zeppelin. For version >0.9 the %dep has been removed. Please refer to the latest [doc](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html#dependency-management)

[image]